# Asterisk in for loop not working as expected?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I don't understand why this is not working. I am trying to loop through files and folders and delete some of them depending on the name. In the example below delete all folders except the ones in the `if` statement.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

workdir=/var/www/
for dir in $workdir/custom/*; do
 if ! [ "$dir" == "$workdir/custom/somefolder" ]; then
   rm -rf $dir
   echo "remove $dir $?"
 fi
 echo "$dir"
done
```

The problem is that there are several files and folders in `/custom/` but `echo "$dir"` outputs `/var/www/custom/*` once
instead of running through every file and folder in that directory. I know this means that * didn't match anything, but this is impossible.

**The folder exists, has several files and folders in it and the path is correct, also the user has all needed permissions to rm files, I checked that twice.**

What am I missing?

Comment: if `$dir` is `/var/www/custom/*` then it means the wildcard didn't match anything. Are you sure you have the pathname correct?

Comment: perhaps globbing is turned off?  try `set +f`

Comment: Why are you using a loop instead of something like `rm -rf "$workdir/custom/"{somefolder,otherfolder,...}`?

Comment: What does `ls /var/www/custom/*` show?

Comment: do you want to remove the files and directories or just the files inside the directories. you might want to use a find command. find /var/www/custom/ -name "*" -type d -exec rm -rf { } \;

Answer (score 0):

```
find /var/www/custom/ -name "*" -type d -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

this will remove all the directories inside your custom directory. If this is what is required.

Comment: sadly I am trying to delete all files and folders except the ones stated in my `if` statement.

Comment: try using it now.. i added mindepth as 1 . this might work.

Comment: the problem with your answer is that it is actually the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. I added an `!` to my `if` in my code description, I forgot to add it.

Comment: Oh got it . You may try using -path /path/to/dirTouDontwantToDelete - prune -o in the find .